# Output is different in iPhone 7 and iPhone 8 Plus (CAShapeLayer)

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I am creating a circular shape object using CAShapeLayer. The output is : when i am using the iPhone 8 Plus, the shape is different. But when i using iPhone 7, the output is different..

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        //Show track layer using CAShapeLayer
        self.trackLayer()

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

func trackLayer()
    {
        //create my track layer
        let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        let center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 2)

        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 105, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

        trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.6).cgColor
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 13
        trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

        self.view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
    }
```

[image: when using iPhone 8 Plus]

[image: when using iPhone 7]

Comment: How are you defining the circle in the centre? Is it not that that’s different?

Comment: distance in circle and "Start" button

Comment: can you show the code for creating the start label and the circle. Show the whole thing

Comment: what is start A button or label, How you are adding it on UI??

Comment: Start is a button